# If $\varphi : G\to G'$ is an homomorphism does it follow that $|\varphi(H)|$ divides $|H|$ for $H\leq G$.

Tags: group-theory

I understand that if $a\in G$ then it follows that $|\varphi(a)|$ divides $|a|$. But I wanted to know if this extends to subgroups of $G$ that aren't generated by a single element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This follows from the first isomorphism theorem, which states that $\varphi$ induces an isomorphism $\varphi(H) \cong H/\ker \varphi$. Since $|H /\ker \varphi| = |H|/|\ker \varphi|$, we're done.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can ignore $G$ completely and just view $\varphi$ as a homomorphism $H\to G'$. Then $|\varphi(H)| = |H|/|\ker \varphi|$.